# Select all lines between two locations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

If I have a +20000 line source code in Eclipse, and I want to select say everything between line 400 and line 12000, how can I do that?

Other than selecting with mouse.

Comment: You can always click the starting point, scroll to the 12000th line, and then hold shift and click at the point.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with Eclipse, but if you have the command line at your disposal, you can do `sed -n '400,12000p' <filename>` and pipe the output to a file or `xclip`. (from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/361/print-all-the-lines-between-10-and-20-of-a-file)